# What is the meaning of the line - " vector<long long> distance(n, std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()); "?

Tags: c++, vector, graph, bellman-ford

Actually I have to find shortest paths from the source vertex to all the other vertices. For this I have been provided with the code template given below. I want to implement " `Bellman–Ford algorithm` ".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using std::vector;
using std::queue;
using std::pair;
using std::priority_queue;

void shortest_paths(vector<vector<int> > &adj, vector<vector<int> > &cost, int s, vector<long long> &distance, vector<int> &reachable, vector<int> &shortest) {
    //write your code here
}

int main() {
    int n, m, s;
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    vector<vector<int> > adj(n, vector<int>());
    vector<vector<int> > cost(n, vector<int>());
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int x, y, w;
        std::cin >> x >> y >> w;
        adj[x - 1].push_back(y - 1);
        cost[x - 1].push_back(w);
    }
    std::cin >> s;
    s--;
    vector<long long> distance(n, std::numeric_limits<long long>::max());
    vector<int> reachable(n, 0);
    vector<int> shortest(n, 1);
    shortest_paths(adj, cost, s, distance, reachable, shortest);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (!reachable[i]) {
            std::cout << "*\n";
        } else if (!shortest[i]) {
            std::cout << "-\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << distance[i] << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to understand the meaning of line " `vector<long long> distance(n, std::numeric_limits<long long>::max());` ". Also what is - " `std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()` " for ?. Can anyone explain it please.

Comment: Have you tried *searching* for e.g. `std::numeric_limits`? What have you found?

Comment: As for the `distance` line, that's just defined a variable `distance`, being of type `std::vector<long long>`, and passing arguments to a  suitable [`std::vector` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (more precisely number three in that reference).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually i got - " The numeric_limits class template provides a standardized way to query various properties of arithmetic types (e.g. the largest possible value for type int is std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) ". But i am unable to understand it. Also why cannot we use " INT_MAX " for this purpose?

Comment: Because `INT_MAX` is the max value for `int` not `long long`.

Comment: `numeric_limits` has more than just min and max.

Comment: You **could** use `LLONG_MAX` instead of `std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()`; the have the same value. But when you're writing a template, `std::numeric_limits<Ty>::max()` works for all numeric types `Ty`, while `LLONG_MAX` works only for `long long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector<long long>` - the type of the variable

`distance` - the variable name

`(n, std::numeric_limits<long long>::max());` - the constructor parameters

`std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()` - `std::numeric_limits` is a class which requires a type parameter (here `long long`) and it has static functions, which return values specialized for this type. In this case the maximum value for `long long`.